# Problem with C# References

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, reference

Hullo,

I'm having trouble with the type `RedirectToRouteResult` in my code, and when I open up the immediate window and put `RedirectToRouteResult` into it then I get the error message:

`The type 'System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult' exists in both 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'System.Web.Mvc.dll'`

I have tried removing the System.Web.Mvc.dll reference and then it just couldn't find RedirectToRouteResult at all.

Anyone have any ideas that could help?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Check to see you might have multiple references(2.0,3.0) of MVC.dll in your app configuration file.

Comment: There isn't an app.config file for this project I'm afraid

Comment: There should be a web.config file, however - check in there.

Comment: There's no .config files through the project. It's a project for testing a web project, by the way

Comment: Do you perhaps load another `System.Web.Mvc.dll` manually?

Comment: Nope, not that I can find at all. This is a very annoying problem

Comment: Did you try a clean operation before build? Or try deleting the bin folder before building?

Comment: @Harold Check your `bin` folder as well. You're not giving us much to go on here. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. My questions keep meaning to be quite explanatory and always end up really vague. It did turn out it was referencing a project that was referencing `System.Web.Mvc.dll` from a different location though :)

Comment: Does that mean you fixed the problem? If so, mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was referencing a project that was referencing the `System.Web.Mvc.dll` from another location. I changed it to point at the same file and it sorted out the problem